# Is there a way to actively listen to server log/response after sending request using httpURLConnection in java?

Tags: java, http, post, response, httpurlconnection

I'm using httpurlconnection to send an xml file in java and I know we can get the response from the server and print it out. Wondering is there a way to actively get the server update log/response like every two seconds?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Http protocol is all about simple request and response. Nothing else. So,for your current task the best way is to implement some sort of server polling.
Some simillar question is here: [Polling an Http server (sending http get requests repeatedly) in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24550906/polling-an-http-server-sending-http-get-requests-repeatedly-in-java)